# How can I format a frame using grid in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wish my interface can be more organize without using .place() too many times.

**I want my interface to look like this:**
[image]

I had tried to do it with grid, but I have a very less knowledge of it and fail to move widgets freely.

**What'ive done:**
[image]

**My code:**

```
root = Tk()
root.title("FOGHORN PUBLISHER")
width = 940
height = 680
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width / 2) - (width / 2)
y = (screen_height / 2) - (height / 2)
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))
root.resizable(0, 0)


def MainMenuForm():
    global ServerDirectoryFrame, ReviewFrame,  lbl_result2
    ServerDirectoryFrame = Frame(root)
    ServerDirectoryFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    lbl_ServerDir = Label(ServerDirectoryFrame, text="Server's Directory of "+ "\n" '''+target_ip''' , font=('arial', 10, "bold"), bd=15 )
    lbl_ServerDir.grid(row=0, column=0)
    global lbox
    lbox = Listbox(ServerDirectoryFrame, width=27, height=35)
    lbox.grid(row=7, column=0)

    ReviewFrame = Frame(root)
    ReviewFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')


    global text
    var = StringVar(root)
    var.set(None)
    jsonRadio = Radiobutton(ReviewFrame, text='JSON', bg="yellow", fg="black")
    jsonRadio.grid()
    xmlRadio = Radiobutton(ReviewFrame, text='XML', bg="yellow", fg="black")
    xmlRadio.grid(row=2)
    text = Text(ReviewFrame, bg='black', foreground="white", height="7", width="96")
    text.grid()
    text.delete('1.0', END)
    text.insert(END, "Opps, not yet connect OR no files to be read....")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widget layout requires a methodical approach. You need to look at the overall design to find groupings of widgets. Create frames for the outer-most groupings, and then for each outer group, look for groupings inside it, and so on. Different groupings may work best with `grid`, and others with `pack`.

It looks like you started down this road, but the way you've organized your code makes it hard to see. You have layout functions mixed in with widget creation, making it extremely hard to visualize what the code is doing. It's important not just to have a good layout strategy, it's also important to organize your code to reflect that strategy.

For your layout, start by creating two frames: one for the left side and one for the right. You can use `pack` to add them to the root window since `pack` is great at creating horizontal or vertical groupings of widgets. If your app behaves like most apps, you want the left side to be fairly static, and let the right grow or shrink as the user resizes the window.

It would look something like this:

```
left = tk.Frame(root)
right = tk.Frame(root)

left.pack(side="left", fill="y")
right.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)
```

With that, you can now focus on just the left side or just the right side without having to try to juggle the layout of all widgets at once.

For the left side, it's not clear if the listbox is supposed to be inside or outside the label. For simplicity, I'll assume it's outside. Since these widgets form a vertical stack, `pack` again is the simplest choice.

```
list_label = tk.Label(left, text="Label")
listbox = tk.Listbox(left)
list_label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
listbox.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
```

For the right, it looks like you have at least two sections: a frame of buttons along the top, and then a main area down below with some widgets laid out in a grid. So, create two more frames for those sections.

```
button_frame = tk.Frame(right)
main_frame = tk.Frame(right)

button_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
main_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

For the buttons, `grid` is a good choice since you seem to want three evenly spaced columns.

```
button_frame.grid_columnconfigure((0,1,2), weight=1)
rb1 = tk.Radiobutton(button_frame, text="rb 1")
rb2 = tk.Radiobutton(button_frame, text="rb 2")
rb3 = tk.Radiobutton(button_frame, text="rb 3")

rb1.grid(row=0, column=0)
rb2.grid(row=0, column=1)
rb3.grid(row=0, column=2)
```

Finally, the bottom area seems to have four widgets: three text entry widgets and a button. It's unclear if you want them each inside a visible frame or not, or whether they should fill the frame or have the large margins shown in the drawing. For simplicity, I'll assume you don't want the visible frames, but I'll keep the margins.

The layout for these widgets is slightly more complicated. You appear to have a grid where the top text spans all three columns of the first row, and then you have additional text widgets in columns 0 and 2 of the second row. You then have a button in the middle column of the third row.

That might look something like this:

```
text1 = tk.Text(main_frame, width=50, height=10, bd=1, relief="sunken")
text2 = tk.Text(main_frame, width=20, height=10, bd=1, relief="sunken")
text3 = tk.Text(main_frame, width=20, height=10, bd=1, relief="sunken")
button = tk.Button(main_frame, text="Button")

main_frame.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1), weight=1)
main_frame.grid_columnconfigure((0, 2), weight=1)

text1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=4)
text2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=20, pady=4)
text3.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nsew", padx=20, pady=4)
button.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

This yields a very responsive layout, which means you don't have to force the window to a specific size. Pick reasonable defaults for the size of the interior widgets and tkinter will compute an optimal window size. If the user needs to resize the window, the widgets will all grow or shrink in a predictable way.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks ! , you explained it very well ! . I finally understand how to organized my frame and widgets etc. Kudos for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use the `grid` geometry manager, then you will need to play around with `columnspan` and `rowspan` option, refer to the below code as an example

```py
ServerDirectoryFrame=Frame()
ServerDirectoryFrame.grid(row=0,column=0)
lbl_ServerDir = Label(ServerDirectoryFrame, text="Server's Directory of "+ "\n" '''+target_ip''' , font=('arial', 10, "bold"), bd=15 )
lbl_ServerDir.grid(row=0,column=0)
lbox = Listbox(ServerDirectoryFrame, width=27, height=35)
lbox.grid(row=1,column=0)

ReviewFrame=Frame()
ReviewFrame.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='n')

jsonRadio = Radiobutton(ReviewFrame, text='JSON', bg="yellow", fg="black")
jsonRadio.grid(row=0,column=0)
xmlRadio = Radiobutton(ReviewFrame, text='XML', bg="yellow", fg="black")
xmlRadio.grid(row=0,column=1)

text = Text(ReviewFrame, bg='black', foreground="white", height="7", width="96")
text.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2)
```

If you wish to go with `pack` geometry manager, you can try to divide your layout into multiple frames, and then nest the respective widgets and frames inside them. Refer to the below code as an example

```py
left_frame=Frame()
left_frame.pack(side='left',fill='y')

right_frame=Frame()
right_frame.pack(side='right',fill='y')

ServerDirectoryFrame=Frame(left_frame)
ServerDirectoryFrame.pack(side='top')
lbl_ServerDir = Label(ServerDirectoryFrame, text="Server's Directory of "+ "\n" '''+target_ip''' , font=('arial', 10, "bold"), bd=15 )
lbl_ServerDir.pack(side='top')
lbox = Listbox(ServerDirectoryFrame, width=27, height=35)
lbox.pack(side='top')

ReviewFrame=Frame(right_frame)
ReviewFrame.pack()

radiobutton_frame=Frame(ReviewFrame)
radiobutton_frame.pack(side='top')
jsonRadio = Radiobutton(radiobutton_frame, text='JSON', bg="yellow", fg="black")
jsonRadio.pack(side='left')
xmlRadio = Radiobutton(radiobutton_frame, text='XML', bg="yellow", fg="black")
xmlRadio.pack(side='left')

text = Text(ReviewFrame, bg='black', foreground="white", height="7", width="96")
text.pack(side='top')
```